# SQL alchemy date time format rather than YYYY/MM/DD, wanted to be DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I want to change the format is it possible?

I am using `pandas` `df.to_sql` function to pass the data.

```
import sqlalchemy as alch

df.to_sql(tab_name,con=engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', 
        dtype={
            'product_id': alch.CHAR(36),
            'product_name': alch.VARCHAR(100),
            'product_type': alch.VARCHAR(50),
            'product_description': alch.VARCHAR(300),
            'product_date_cr': alch.DateTime(),
            'product_date_up': alch.DateTime(),
            'product_by_cr': alch.VARCHAR(50),
            'product_by_up': alch.VARCHAR(50)
        })
```

Comment: If you are storing date values in a proper date/datetime column then they do not have a format *per se*; they are stored as an internal numeric value. They may have a *default string representation* like `yyyy-mm-dd` but if you want date/datetime values to appear in a specific format like `dd-mm-yyyy` it's up to you to apply that formatting yourself.